# Encountering Syntax Error in Ansible Playbook When Using replace and lineinfile Modules

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm working with an Ansible playbook to configure `StopIdleSessionSec` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` on RHEL8 servers. However, I'm stuck with a syntax error that suggests mixing 'k=v' shorthand syntax with YAML. Here's what I've tried:

Using the replace module:

```yaml
- name: Ensure StopIdleSessionSec is set correctly in logind.conf 
  replace: 
    path: /etc/systemd/logind.conf
    regexp: '^(#?StopIdleSessionSec=).*' 
    replace: 'StopIdleSessionSec=900' 
  notify: restart systemd-logind
```

Using the lineinfile module:

```yaml
 - name: Ensure StopIdleSessionSec is set correctly 
   lineinfile: 
     path: /etc/systemd/logind.conf 
     regexp: '^(#?StopIdleSessionSec=).*' 
     line: 'StopIdleSessionSec=900' 
     state: present 
   notify: restart systemd-logind
```

Both methods result in an error:

"There appears to be both 'k=v' shorthand syntax and YAML in this task. Only one syntax may be used."

I'm not sure what's causing this since I'm using YAML syntax consistently. How can I resolve this issue to correctly set `StopIdleSessionSec` without syntax errors? Any insights or fixes would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add code blocks to format your code and output correctly. Thanks.

Comment: @jspaine I have edited your question to display the yaml correctly.  Please edit your question with the output from running your playbook.

Comment: Based on the give tasks I am not able to reproduce that (syntax) issue. It should run without the error message. Maybe this is a [Misleading error message when one YAML line is malformed and another contains equals sign #75995](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/75995) or somewhere else in the playbook which is not shown. We would need to see the debug output and the full error message mentioning the line.

Comment: Is it really an error given by executing this playbook or is it a linter?

Comment: @Squashman I looked up the original code and decided to _not_ fix the question. There was no line breaks there, so chances are that the issue was really caused by the original formatting.